# cant find libl on centos 9 - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll

Tags: c, linux, centos, lex

Brand new install of centos 9. (mostly minimal)

I did a find and there is no libl.so on my machine.

sudo yum install bison
Last metadata expiration check: 1:52:29 ago on Wed 23 Feb 2022 01:25:31 PM EST.
Package bison-3.7.4-5.el9.x86_64 is already installed.

sudo yum install flex
Last metadata expiration check: 1:52:25 ago on Wed 23 Feb 2022 01:25:31 PM EST.
Package flex-2.6.4-9.el9.x86_64 is already installed.

sudo yum install flex-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 1:52:35 ago on Wed 23 Feb 2022 01:25:31 PM EST.
No match for argument: flex-devel

I tried installing sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'

nothing works, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static libraries (`libfl.a` and `libl.a`), which is what were provided before in the package `flex-devel`, have been moved to the package `libfl-static`. I don't know if RedHat ever provided shared objects; there's a note in the libfl-static ChangeLog that seems to be saying that there is a new package called `libfl2` with shared objects, but I don't see it in the package repo. Anyway, static libraries should be fine. There's hardly anything there.

If you're using `libl`, that means that:

- you aren't using `%option noyywrap`, which will remove the call to `yywrap` (and if you're using the version of `yywrap` in `libl`, then you don't need it to call the function, since that version unconditionally returns 1), and/or
- you haven't provided your own `main` function.

I strongly recommend including the following options in all flex files, unless you have a clear need for the suppressed features:

```
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault
```

The `main` function in `libl` is also trivial. It can be replaced with:

```c
int main(void) {
  while (yylex() != 0) { }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the hint here, I assumed it was a shared libarary, I was able to get the static libaries using: dnf --enablerepo=crb install libfl-static

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out in the question - `flex-devel` is not found.

It's in the `PowerTools` repo.

The 'official' way to enable the repo is to use the yum config-manager command line:

```
yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

This may give an error about being missing the `config-manager` command:

```
No such command: config-manager
```

If this happens, then you can install the dnf-plugins-core package:

```
yum install -y dnf-plugins-core
```

and then enable the powertools repo, and then you should be able to `yum install flex-devel`, which provides:

```
$ rpmquery --list flex-devel
/usr/lib64/libfl.a
/usr/lib64/libfl_pic.a
/usr/lib64/libl.a
/usr/share/doc/flex
/usr/share/licenses/flex-devel
/usr/share/licenses/flex-devel/COPYING
```

Comment: when I try:  sudo yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
Error: No matching repo to modify: powertools.

Comment: also I was able to yum install -y dnf-plugins-core, but after that, install flex-devel still does not work!

Comment: it appears as though the powertools repo is not available in centos 9 yet - I was using rocky, rather than centos as I prefer a smidgen more stability.